# XQuery 3.0 в Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xquery

Есть ли возможность обновить XQuery в SQLServer? Нужна версия 3.0, а по умолчанию стоит 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой возможности нет.

SQL Server использует версию 1.0 - `Transact-SQLподдерживает подмножество языка XQuery, используемого для запроса типа данных XML . Эта реализация XQuery совпадает с рабочим эскизом XQuery на июль 2004 г.`

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)